# Cannot resolve symbol 'router-outlet'

Tags: angular

The project is based on Angular 13.

Added routing to the project.
app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {HomePageComponent} from "./home-page/home-page.component";

const appRoutes: Routes =[
  { path: '', component: HomePageComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

added AppRoutingModule to the file app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {ModalModule} from "ngb-modal";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from "./app-routing.module";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomePageComponent
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but if I try to add to the file app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

IDEA throws an error

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'router-outlet'
```

But if I open another project with routing in the same IDE, there is no such error.

Comment: If this project is build is using Angular 13?

Comment: Yes, the project is based on Angular 13

Comment: Do I get this right, your application builds and works like expected, but your IDE displays an error?

Comment: Yes, the routing works. But I don't understand why there is no such error on another project in the same IDE. Maybe something needs to be added to the settings.

Comment: Sorry, I have this problem, how do you resolved it? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

I guess you are using WebStorm as an IDE, since i also ran into that warning when i upgraded my project to Angular 13, yet i didn't it on VSC.

Apparently in order to solve it you need to upgrade WebStorm to 2021.3. I recommend using [JetBrains's toolbox app](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/), which makes it easy to update.

Comment: Yes, indeed this is a problem in the IDE. I hope they will fix it in the new version.

Comment: Upgrading from WebStorm 2021.1.2 to 2022.2.1 corrected the problem for me where router-outlet wasn't being recognized in the IDE. JetBrains documents the problem here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4409379867154-Angular-13-and-message-Cannot-resolve-symbol-for-router-outlet-?sort_by=created_at

Comment: Damn, I'm on perpetual fallback for 2021.2. Oh well, I'll have to live with it I guess. Almost same case. My new Angular 14 project has the issue, while my several Angular 8 ones don't.

Answer (score 1):

Hello =)  I had the same problem today. I solved it like that:

- I closed my IDE (IntelliJ)
- I opened JetBrains ToolBox to update the IDE
- The "node_modules" repository of my project is **excluded from index**, expect "node_modules/@angular" repo (right click on it, 'Mark Directory as' --> 'Not Excluded')
- Rebuild or reopen the project

Now it works, on my side : with IntelliJ, all router elements and all native pipes are properly detected. Hope it could help ^^